# Can't update django datetime field to Null

Tags: python, django, django-models

My code is

```
Message.objects.filter(id=message_id).update(read_at='Null')
```

getting this error

> ValidationError: [u'Enter a valid date/time in YYYY-MM-DD
>   HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]] format.']

and the model is

```
read_at = models.DateTimeField(_("read at"), null=True, blank=True)
```

Is there any way to update datetime to null? Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django update calls are written in Python rather than SQL - use `None` instead:

```
Message.objects.filter(id=message_id).update(read_at=None)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Message.objects.filter(id=message_id).update(read_at=None)
```